# Taking info from a File

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

This is my code;

```
Import os
#hard code the path to the external file
external_file = 'names.txt'
username = 'testuser'# Our hardcoded name

#if file doesn't exists, create a new file
if not os.path.exists(external_file):
    #Ask the user's name
    name = raw_input("What's your name?")
    with open(external_file, "a") as f: # using "a" will append to the file
        f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    #if file exists, use it to load name, else ask user
    with open(external_file, "r+") as f:# r+ open a file for reading & writing
        lines = f.read().split('\n') # split the names 
        print lines
        if username in lines: #Check if the file has any username as 'testuser'
            print "Hi {}".format(username)
        else: # If there is no username as 'testuser' then ask for a name
            name = raw_input("What's your name?")
            f.seek(0,2) # Resolves an issue in Windows
            f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()
```

This is good and working code but I don't want it to have a list of names being displayed and it asking you to pick. I want it to store only one name and draw that name everytime the programme is turned on unless you tell it otherwise
E.g;

```
IsName = raw_input("That is your name, right?")
If 'no' in IsName:
```

Then the code to change the name on file

Comment: instead of `open(external_file, "a")` use `open(external_file, "w")` which will overwrite instead of append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code with comments. Is this want you want?
This works as below:

1. The code first check if there is a file named `names.txt`, if there is no such file it will create a new file `names.txt` and then ask for a name. Then it will save this name to the file `names.txt`
2. If the file `names.txt` already exists then it will open the file and check if it contains our hardcoded name that is `testuser`. If it contains the `testuser` then it will say:

   Hi testuser
   Is this your name?

If the user enters `no` then it will ask for a new name and write it to the `names.txt` file. If the `names.txt` file exists and it doesn't contains the hardcoded name `testuser`, then programme will ask for name and write it to the `names.txt` file.

**Code**:

```
import os
#hard code the path to the external file
external_file = 'names.txt'
username = 'testuser'#Our hardcoded name

#if file doesn' exists, create a new file
if not os.path.exists(external_file):
    #Ask the user's name
    name = raw_input("What's your name?")
    with open(external_file, "a") as f: #using "a" will append to the file
        f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    #if file exists, use it to load name, else ask user
    with open(external_file, "r") as f:#r+ opens a file for reading & writing
        lines = f.read().split('\n') # split the names 
        f.close()
    if username in lines: #Check if the file has any username as 'testuser'
        print "Hi {}".format(username)
        response = raw_input("Is this your name?")
        if 'no' in response.lower():
            name = raw_input("What's your name?")# Asks for new name
            with open(external_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()
    else: # If there is no username as 'testuser' then ask for a name
        name = raw_input("What's your name?")
        with open(external_file, "w") as f:# Write name to the file
            #f.seek(0,2) # Resolves an issue in Windows
            f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()
```

**Modified code**:

```
import os
#hard code the path to the external file
external_file = 'names.txt'

#if file doesn' exists, create a new file
if not os.path.exists(external_file):
    #Ask the user's name
    name = raw_input("What's your name?")
    with open(external_file, "a") as f: #using "a" will append to the file
        f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    #if file exists, use it to load name, else ask user
    with open(external_file, "r") as f:#r+ opens a file for reading & writing
        lines = f.read().split('\n') # split the names 
        f.close()
        print "Hi {}".format(lines[0])
        response = raw_input("Is this your name?")
        if 'no' in response.lower():
            name = raw_input("What's your name?") # Asks for new name
            with open(external_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(name)# Write the name to names.txt
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()
```